# restore scroll position uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view that leads to a detail view. When I click back from the table view I return to the top of the table. I would like it to return to the position of the selected row. I know I can use scroll to position but it needs an index path. Am I right in thinking I need to create a index path property and use that in the method call. If so, where do I populate it - in the did select row/cell method? I have sections in my table so would it be index path section, index path row? And finally is it to be called in view did appear?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe u looking for this:

```
tableView.contentOffset.y;
```

If you mean - you back from detail controller to ur master controller, u can scroll to position in viewWillAppear method (save tableView.contentOffset.y in viewWillDissapear). But i created new project and there no need to do this, it automatically open master controller with saved position when back from detail

Answer (score 0):

It should work using 
`- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated` using it this way:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedRow inSection:yourSection];
[yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                             animated:YES];
```

`atScrollPosition` could take any of these values:

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewScrollPositionNone,
    UITableViewScrollPositionTop,
    UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle,
    UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
} UITableViewScrollPosition;
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you. Only questions - how do I get the selected row and selected section index paths. I've placed all this in viewdidappear - is that correct?

Comment: You can get indexPath in didselect method.........and dont put that in viewDidAppear coz it would be called when you are coming to your tableview class in you lt second view controller fire NsNotufication to do the task